# Table per hierarchy mapping to an existing database using Fluent NHibernate without discriminator column

Tags: .net, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a problem with table per hierarchy mapping to an existing database using Fluent NHibernate (1.2.0.712).
Here is the simplified case.

My class structure:

[image: Class Diagram]

Database structure:

[image: Database diagram]

So basically, we have 1 table (Entities) which contains some specific data (Id and Name) + several foreign keys (to ReferencedObject1 OR ReferencedObject2).

Abstract class AbstractEntity contains Id and Name. ConcreteEntity1 and ConcreteEntity2 are derived classes.

I would like to map these derived instances depending on references in database, so
If there is a reference to ReferencedObject1 -> it is an instance of ConcreteEntity1.
If there is a reference to ReferencedObject2 -> it is an instance of ConcreteEntity2.

Some code:

```
public class AbstractEntity
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
public class ConcreteEntity1 : AbstractEntity
{
    public virtual ReferencedObject1 ReferencedObject1 { get; set; }
}
public class ConcreteEntity2 : AbstractEntity
{
    public virtual ReferencedObject2 ReferencedObject2 { get; set; }
}


public class AbstractEntityMap : ClassMap<AbstractEntity>
{
    public AbstractEntityMap()
    {
        Table("Entities");
        Id(e => e.Id);
        Map(e => e.Name);
    }
}
```

So actually my question is how should I map derived classes?
I've looked through fluent nhibernate wiki and found that

> If you wanted to do a table-per-class-hierarchy strategy, then you just need to specify the discriminator column in your ClassMap.

but, as far as I understand, I do not have a discriminator column. My case is to determine subclass depending on foreign key references.

> Note: For multiple discriminator columns use a DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("").Formula([insert custom sql here])

I can't find a good example of formula usage. Can it be helpful in my case? And I'm a little bit confused, maybe I am doing something wrong?

Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("")
    .Formula(case when ReferencedObject1id > 0 then 1 else case when ReferencedObject2id > 0 then 2 else ... end)

ConcreteEntity1Map()
{
    DiscriminatorValue(1);
}
```